# .each() em Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, paginação

Em uma plataforma de fóruns existe um sistema de paginação, e eu gostaria de fazer essa paginação via Ajax, para isso, construi a seguinte função:

```
//<![CDATA[
var Pagination = (function(w, d) {
    var pagination = {

        init: function() {
            this.run();
        },

        run: function() {

            w.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var links = d.querySelectorAll('p.paging a[href^="/t"]');

                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

                        event.preventDefault();

                        var link = this.getAttribute('href'),
                            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.onload = function() {
                            d.querySelector('.main').innerHTML = this.responseXML.querySelector('.main').innerHTML;
                        };
                        xhr.open('GET', link);
                        xhr.responseType = 'document';
                        xhr.send();
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    };

    pagination.init();

}(window, document));
//]]>
```

Ele funciona perfeito até o primeiro clique. Porém se eu clicar em mais de um link a função não funciona de forma alguma e a página é carregada normalmente.

Eu tenho quase certeza que o erro é no meu laço `for()`, eu não encontrei uma maneira melhor de fazer a função Ajax para cada vez que eu clicar em um link dessa paginação.

Se houver alguma maneira melhor, fico grato em saber.

@Edit:

A estrutura do meu HTML é mais ou menos da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="main">
    <p class="paging">
        <a href="/topic/1">1</a>
        <a href="/topic/2">2</a>
        <a href="/topic/3">3</a>
    </p>
    <div class="topic">
        <div class="content">Conteúdo aqui.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você está clicando em links que já existiam na página, ou em links que foram acrescentados após a primeira chamada do ajax? P.S. à primeira vista, não parece ter nada de errado em seu laço for.

Comment: @mgibsonbr
Eles já existem na página, eles são criados via PHP (o qual não temos acesso), normalmente ao clicar ele vai redirecionar para a próxima página.. Eu ja tentei várias maneiras mas ainda não consegui um resultado satisfatório. Ele funciona no primeiro clique mas deixa de funcionar a partir dos cliques seguintes.. Como se eu estivesse usando document.querySelector()

Comment: O console aponta algum erro?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, não, ele não mostra nenhum erro. Nem warning, nada..

Comment: @waghcwb os links do `.paging a` estão dentro do `.main`?

Comment: Já experimentou isolar a lógica dessa "classe" pra ver se funciona?

Comment: @Sergio, era exatamente isso amigo. Troquei o seletor para um que não incluísse a paginação dentro dele, e funcionou perfeitamente. Eu agradeço a atenção de todos vocês amigos, vocês são demais!

Comment: @waghcwb ótimo! Se quiser apague a pergunta; ou coloque HTML para eu, ou você, poder responder e talvez ser util para outros.

Comment: @Sergio, feito amigo.. Melhor deixar para o conteúdo disponível para todos, talvez algum dia alguém enfrente o mesmo problema.

Comment: @waghcwb, surgiu-me uma duvida quando colocou o HTML. Você está a re-escrever o HTML dentro do main cada vez que faz um pedido AJAX, certo? isso vai fazer com que perca os event handlers... assim ou corre `pagination.init();` a cada sucesso do AJAX ou substitui só o conteudo do `.topic`. Qual está a fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neste seu código está a substituir o menu cada vez que carrega a div `.main`. Isso faz com que os event handlers se percam.

Vejo duas opções:

**mudar o seletor na callback do ajax** para mudar o conteudo certo.
Substituindo para:

```
d.querySelector('.topic').innerHTML = this.responseXML.querySelector('.topic').innerHTML;
```

e assim mudar só o conteudo relevante e não quebrar os oscultadores de eventos colocados pela sua `pagination.run();`

**voltando a colocar os event hadlers a cada vez que carregar novo conteudo**, uma vez que reescrever elementos do DOM faz com que eles percam os event handlers que tinham agarrados.
Assim na callback do ajax pode usar:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    d.querySelector('.main').innerHTML = this.responseXML.querySelector('.main').innerHTML;
    pagination.init();  // ou pagination.run();
};
```

Comment: Olá, tenho uma questão semelhante, e gostaria de saber se você poderia me orientar? O  var fbShareBtn = document.querySelector('.fb-share'); Está retornando apenas o primeiro share button, uso vários botões de compartilhamento do Facebook em uma mesma página (paginação) e apenas o primeiro funciona. Você pode estar vendo todo o código nesse site: http://tedshd.logdown.com/posts/200979-javascript-custom-facebook-share-button

Comment: @ThiagoJem o `querySelector` seleciona só o primeiro elemento que encontra. Tens de usar `querySelectorAll` e depois iterar os elementos com um `for`, se precisares de ajuda coloca uma pergunta nova no site que a gente ajuda no que estiveres a falhar.

Comment: Coloquei a pergunta... pode estar vendo-a aqui: [Link para a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50872/como-retornar-o-elemento-espec%C3%ADfico-de-acordo-com-o-clique-no-mesmo-usando-que)