# Como retornar o elemento específico, ao usar multiplos botões de compartilhar personalizado na mesma página, usando querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Esse share button personalizado do Facebook funciona muito bem, quando se coloca apenas um botão em cada página. (Esse é um excelente caminho para tornar projetos feito em Ajax e JavaScript rastreáveis aos buscadores e redes sociais).

Ao colocar multiplos botões em uma mesma página tive problemas com o `querySelector` (Na documentação consta que o `querySelector` retorna o primeiro elemento dentro do documento...), só que ainda não sei como fazer para retornar apenas o elemento que foi clicado.

Gostaria de uma orientação abalizada, para poder concluir uma parte dessa longa busca, para tornar os shares buttons rastreáveis.

@Sergio obrigado pela introdução no comentário , mas, ainda não consegui colocar em harmonia o `querySelectorAll` com a iteração com o `for`, então concatenei a pergunta como orientou.

Essa é a parte correspondente ao arquivo de origem, editada e adquada ao meu projeto, você pode estar vendo o post originário nesse site: [botão compartilhar do Facebook personalizável](http://tedshd.logdown.com/posts/200979-javascript-custom-facebook-share-button)

Html

```
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
<a fb-share ng-href="http://www.exemplo.com/{{item.href}}" data-image="{{item.img}}" data-title="{{item.titulo}}" data-desc="{{item.descricao}}" class="fb_share"  >
    <div class="botao-fb"></div>
</a>
```

CSS: para inserir a imagem de forma mais prática

```
.botao-fb {
 width: 101px;
 height: 20px; 
background-image:url(/images/fb-icone.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;  
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Diretiva com o script

```
    .directive('fbShare', ['$window', function ($window) {
      return {
        scope:{
            fbShare: '='
        },
        restrict: 'AE',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '1405211842504456', //esse AppId é apenas demonstrativo, substitua com o seu
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    (function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];if   (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));

    function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image) {
        var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture: 'http://www.exemplo.com/images/'+image,name: title,description: desc};
        function callback(response) {}
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }

    var fbShareBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.fb_share');
    for (var i = 0; i < fb_share.length; i++) {
        console.log(fb_share[i]);
    };
    fbShareBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-title'),
            desc = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-desc'),
            url = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('href'),
            image = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-image');
        postToFeed(title, desc, url, image);

        return false;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se usas o `querySelectorAll` tens de iterar os elementos e juntar-lhes o event handler assim:

```
function fbShareBtnFn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = this.getAttribute('data-title'),
        desc = this.getAttribute('data-desc'),
        url = this.getAttribute('href'),
        image = this.getAttribute('data-image');
    postToFeed(title, desc, url, image);
    return false;
};
var fbShareBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.fb_share');
for (var i = 0; i < fbShareBtns.length; i++) {
    fbShareBtns[i].addEventListener('click', fbShareBtnFn);
};
```

E uma vez que o Event handler é chamado para cada elemento o `this` dentro dessa função corresponde ao elemento clicado.

Comment: Funcionou quase que perfeitamente, apenas o segundo elemento está abrindo repetidamente; abrem dois diálogos do facebook quando eu clico no botão, que é o segundo elemento da lista na paginação. Vou estar analisando direito aqui pode ser que seja algo nos demais códigos.

Comment: Deixei 3 itens na mesma página na paginação, para fazer o teste melhor, aconteceu que ao cliar no 1° abriram-se 3 diálogos do mesmo artigo, ao clicar no 2° abriram-se 2 diálogos do mesmo artigo,  e ao clicar no terceiro abriu 1, que é o ideal.

Comment: @Sergio, apenas uma sugestão, quando quiser acessar um atributo `data-*`, dê preferencia ao `dataset` ao invés do `getAttribute`, acredito que isto melhore a legibilidade.

Comment: @ThiagoJem não estou no escritório... já conseguiste resolver os erros?

Comment: @TobyMosque o `dataset` é suportado só no IE11, apesar de ser essa a maneira correta no futuro, sugeri a maneira segura cross-browser.

Comment: @Sergio, tinha esquecido deste detalhe, espero que com o Spartan a MS consiga forçar a atualização do Browser.

Comment: @TobyMosque isso seria excelente (se a MS adotar atualização obrigatória do browser)... ia poupar muita dor de cabeça :)

Answer (score 1):

Em complemento a resposta do @Sergio eu precisei acrescentar o `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` (que mantém o resto dos manipuladores de ser executado e impede que o evento borbulhando a árvore DOM.),

Pois, uso multiplos botões do facebook em uma paginação e estava abrindo vários diálogos ao clicar no botão. Agora está funcionando bem.

```
function fbShareBtnFn(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    var title = this.getAttribute('data-title'),
        desc = this.getAttribute('data-desc'),
        url = this.getAttribute('href'),
        image = this.getAttribute('data-image');
    postToFeed(title, desc, url, image);
// retirei o 'return false;' e coloquei o 'event.stopImmediatePropagation();'
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
};
var fbShareBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.fb_share');
for (var i = 0; i < fbShareBtns.length; i++) {
    fbShareBtns[i].addEventListener('click', fbShareBtnFn);
};
```